# Python accessing specific elements on Menards website

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I am currently trying to create a python script that can go into Menards website and grab all their products descriptions, SKU, and price and then imports them into an excel file. So I can then create pivot tables or do other stuff with their products. Currently, I was able to make it work by using XPath and etc. But this method is not very robust since it relies on the specific path for each different webpages. What I want to do is make something more robust that can be used on the website I'm looking at.
These are the websites I am referring to.

```
https://www.menards.com/main/electrical/conduit-conduit-fittings-raceways/conduit/c-6423.htm?queryType=allItems&rid=ipKkIrbnch&shippingOptions_facet=Pickup+at+Store+Eligible'
https://www.menards.com/main/electrical/conduit-conduit-fittings-raceways/conduit-fittings-supports/c-9538.htm queryType=allItems&shippingOptions_facet=Pickup+at+Store+Eligible&sortby=priceAsc'
https://www.menards.com/main/electrical/light-switches-dimmers-outlets/light-switches/c-6324.htm?queryType=allItems&Spec_Color%2FFinishFamily_facet=Ivory&Spec_Color%2FFinishFamily_facet=Light+Almond&Spec_Color%2FFinishFamily_facet=White&shippingOptions_facet=Pickup+at+Store+Eligible&sortby=priceAsc/'
```

IRW = https://www.menards.com/main/electrical/electrical-wire-cable/indoor-electrical-cable/c-6441.htm?queryType=allItems&rid=HA1P3WveKh&shippingOptions_facet=Pickup+at+Store+Eligible

This is the code that I have currently have in trying to figure out a more robust design.

```
driver.get(website.get('IRW'))
driver.minimize_window()
description = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".search-item")
print(len(description))
for ll in range(0, 1):
    print(description[ll].text)
```

Currently, this code just locates all of the elements on the webpage by its class name "search-items". Which locates most of the elements and such but however I get a lot of garbage with the results I want.
Here is an example of what I am output of the code:

```
> 11 Click here to go to detail page Bestseller 12 Variations Available
> 12 Gauge NM-B Cable with Ground Wire Click to add item "12 Gauge NM-B
> Cable with Ground Wire" to the compare list Compare Click to add item
> "12 Gauge NM-B Cable with Ground Wire" to the compare list Add To List
> Click to add item 12 Gauge NM-B Cable with Ground Wire to your list
> Sku # 3691660 $25.79 You Save $3.19 with Mail-In Rebate More
> Information Shipping CHOOSE VARIATION None
```

I want to avoid having to replace the current string and do a lot of loops in order to get the values since all of this garbage is not consistent on every webpage. I am hoping that is a better way to locate the elements. Any ideas thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the css child `>` and descendant   combinators to specify direct children or descendants (respectively) of parents with class `search-item`, in a sequence that isolates just the hrefs of interest

```
links = [i.text for i in 
         driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#search-items > .search-item .details > a")]
```

Comment: this is very helpful over how can I can access other classes in which is the class name has spaces in between?

Comment: this is very helpful over how can I can access other classes in which is the class name has spaces in between? Currently is spitting this: Click here to go to detail page
12 Variations Available
14 Gauge NM-B Cable with Ground Wire, I really just want the description of the product.

Comment: if there are spaces then replace with `.`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you QHarr I was able to figure out how to access other classes with this specific class. The line of code that allows me to do this is as follows:

```
#for description
description = [i.text for i in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#search-items > .search-item .details > a > .row.pt-5.pb-sm-5 > .multilines-3.text-truncate-multilines.xs-single-col-8.col-12 > .font-weight-bold.text-dark")]
print(description)
```